# How to dynamically add and remove GROUPS to KendoUI Scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using KendoUI Scheduler control and here is initialization code

```
                  $("#Scheduler").kendoScheduler({

                       dataSource: [],
                       selectable: true,
                       height: 500,
                       editable: false,
                       eventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),
                       views: [
                               "day",
                               { type: "week", selected: true },
                               "month",
                               "agenda"
                       ],
                       resources: [
                             {
                                 field: "resourceviewid",
                                 name: "ResourceViews",
                                 dataColorField: "key",
                                 dataSource: [
                                     { text: "Appointments", value: 1, key: "orange" },
                                     { text: "Delivery Specialist", value: 2, key: "blue" },
                                     { text: "Orientation Specialist", value: 3, key: "green" }
                                 ]
                             }
                       ],
                       group: {
                           resources: ["ResourceViews"],
                           orientation: "horizontal"
                       }
                   });
```

**Here "Appointments" group is default, it will be available always**

I have check box in my screen

```
        <div id="divResourceView">
            <label><input checked type="checkbox" value="1" />Delivery Specialist</label>
            <label><input checked type="checkbox" value="2" />Orientation Specialist</label>
        </div>
```

On change event I wrote below code to get selected values from checkbox and updating **GROUP** datasource of KendoUI scheduler as below

```
        $("#divResourceView :checkbox").change(function (e) {
        var checked = $.map($("#divResourceView :checked"), function (checkbox) {
            return parseInt($(checkbox).val());
           });
        });

        var scheduler = $("#Scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

        var arrayOfStrings = checked.toString().split(",");

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++)
        {
            if(arrayOfStrings[i] == 1)
            {
                var data = [{ text: "Delivery Specialist", value: 2, color: "blue" }];
                scheduler.resources[1].dataSource.data(data);
            }
            if (arrayOfStrings[i] == 2) {
                var data = [{ text: "Orientation Specialist", value: 3, color: "green" }];
                scheduler.resources[2].dataSource.data(data);
            }
        }

        scheduler.refresh();
```

But it removes all groups and add only one. I want to see both groups when **arrayOfStrings** has values "1,2",

**I can see all groups during initialization** But it disappears when i check the check box.

**Images for reference** 
During Initialization
[image]

After
[image]

**As you can see clearly, Delivery Specialist is missing in scheduler control**

Found some link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/add-filter-to-resource-datasource
But not sure what they talking about? seems like refresh issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this I believe you're right and your issue is to do with refreshing, I use the following to refresh it.

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
```

hope this helps through it is stupidly late (I'm currently looking up how to do this lazerly